# Creating view with 2 foreign keys of one table

Tags: mysql, view, foreign-keys

`releases.studio_id` and `releases.publisher_id` both refer to `companies.id`. I tried

```
CREATE VIEW v_releases AS
SELECT releases.id AS 'id', 
 games.name AS name,
 companies.name AS studio,
 companies.name AS publisher
FROM releases
Left JOIN games ON releases.game_id = games.id
Left JOIN companies ON releases.studio_id = companies.id 
                   AND releases.publisher_id = companies.id;
```

but the resulting view shows mostly null in `studio_id` and `publisher_id` where each record should contain references. Testing

```
CREATE VIEW v_releases AS
SELECT releases.id AS 'id', 
 games.name AS name,
 companies.name AS studio,
 companies.name AS publisher
FROM releases
Left JOIN games ON releases.game_id = games.id
Left JOIN companies ON releases.studio_id = companies.id;
```

results in strangely having `publisher_id` as an exact copy of the `studio_id` column, while the `studio_id` column has all correct data. How to create a view with correct references from these two foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they are different you need to join companies twice, to catch each name

```
CREATE VIEW v_releases AS
SELECT releases.id AS 'id', 
 games.name AS name,
 c1.name AS studio,
 c2.name AS publisher,
FROM releases
Left JOIN games ON releases.game_id = games.id
Left JOIN companies c1 ON releases.studio_id = c1.id 
Left JOIN companies c2 ON  releases.publisher_id = c2.id;
```